# constructor with class parameter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to have `Kotlin` class with constructor and get another class as parameter like this.

```
class LogHelper(cls : class) {

}
```

I had the same class in java and I didn't have any problem with it.

```
public LogHelper(Class cls) {
    LOG_TAG = cls.getSimpleName();
}
```

Comment: Class names typically start with a capital letter.

Comment: @EugenPechanec in java you right, but not in Kotlin

Comment: `class` is a [keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html), [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a Java class. [Class names typically start with a capital letter even in Kotlin.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules)

Comment: @EugenPechanec you right, I find Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use constructor with `java.lang.Class` parameter:

```
class LogHelper(cls: Class<*>) {
    val LOG_TAG = cls.simpleName
}
```

or Kotlin's `KClass`:

```
class LogHelper(cls: KClass<*>) { ... }
```

`*` - [Star Projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections), used to indicate we have no information about a generic argument.

Kotlin does not allow raw generic types (e.g. `Class`), you always have to specify the type parameter (e.g. `Class<*>`, `Class<Any>`, `Class<SomeClass>`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the right answer for my question was KClass<*> and I find out because of your suggestion. Please add it in your answer.

Comment: @Alishatergholi it may be worth mentioning that raw types are heavily discouraged even in Java.

Comment: @Moira do you have any link to explain when we should use raw type.

Comment: @Alishatergholi if possible, [never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). They are not type safe.